# Python popen command. Wait until the command is finished

Tags: python, subprocess, wait, popen

I have a script where I launch with popen a shell command.
The problem is that the script doesn't wait until that popen command is finished and go continues right away.

```
om_points = os.popen(command, "w")
.....
```

How can I tell to my Python script to wait until the shell command has finished?

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Depending on how you want to work your script you have two options. If you want the commands to block and not do anything while it is executing, you can just use `subprocess.call`.

```
#start and block until done
subprocess.call([data["om_points"], ">", diz['d']+"/points.xml"])
```

If you want to do things while it is executing or feed things into `stdin`, you can use `communicate` after the `popen` call.

```
#start and process things, then wait
p = subprocess.Popen([data["om_points"], ">", diz['d']+"/points.xml"])
print "Happens while running"
p.communicate() #now wait plus that you can send commands to process
```

As stated in the documentation, `wait` can deadlock, so communicate is advisable.

Comment: Check out the docs on [subprocess.call](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#convenience-functions)

Comment: While subprocess is preferred in many answers, it cannot handle space and quota within command very well. The above answer does not directly solve the os.popen question.

Comment: subprocess can be up to 2x slower than os system - https://bugs.python.org/issue37790

Comment: `subprocess.run()` was added in Python 3.5 and is "The recommended approach to invoking subprocesses"

Answer (score 45):

You can you use `subprocess` to achieve this.

```
import subprocess

#This command could have multiple commands separated by a new line \n
some_command = "export PATH=$PATH://server.sample.mo/app/bin \n customupload abc.txt"

p = subprocess.Popen(some_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

(output, err) = p.communicate()  

#This makes the wait possible
p_status = p.wait()

#This will give you the output of the command being executed
print "Command output: " + output
```

Comment: subprocess can be up to 2x slower than os system - bugs.python.org/issue37790

Answer (score 24):

Force `popen` to not continue until all output is read by doing:

```
os.popen(command).read()
```

Comment: I'm no python expert, but this seems to be the simplest solution that makes the fewest modifications to the original code. Any reason why this wouldn't be a good solution?

Comment: @jdmcnair my guess is that if the command threw an error, this .read() method would break the parent process. But some other methods decouple errors in the child process from affecting the parent process. I'm guessing that if the child process hangs forever, .read() will wait forever to a result.

Answer (score 14):

Let the command you are trying to pass be

```
os.system('x')
```

then you covert it to a statement

```
t = os.system('x')
```

now the python will be waiting for the output from the commandline so that it could be assigned to the variable `t`.

Answer (score 7):

What you are looking for is the [`wait`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait) method.

Comment: But if I type:
 om_points = os.popen(data["om_points"]+" > "+diz['d']+"/points.xml", "w").wait()
I receive this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./model_job.py", line 77, in <module>
    om_points = os.popen(data["om_points"]+" > "+diz['d']+"/points.xml", "w").wait()
AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'wait'

What is the problem?

Thanks again.

Comment: You did not click on the link I provided. `wait` is a method of the `subprocess` class.

Comment: wait can deadlock if the process writes to stdout and nobody reads it

Comment: subprocess can be up to 2x slower than os system - bugs.python.org/issue37790

Comment: @MonsieurBeilto `os.system` has been deprecated; it has been replaced with `subprocess`

Comment: Also, that bug (https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/81971) was closed for lack of reproducibility and insufficient information about the platform it was seen on.

Answer (score 7):

[wait()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait) works fine for me. The subprocesses p1, p2 and p3 are executed at the same. Therefore, all processes are done after 3 seconds.

```
import subprocess

processes = []

p1 = subprocess.Popen("sleep 3", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
p2 = subprocess.Popen("sleep 3", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
p3 = subprocess.Popen("sleep 3", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

processes.append(p1)
processes.append(p2)
processes.append(p3)

for p in processes:
    if p.wait() != 0:
        print("There was an error")

print("all processed finished")
```

Comment: subprocess can be up to 2x slower than os system - bugs.python.org/issue37790

Answer (score 0):

I think process.communicate() would be suitable for output having small size. For larger output it would not be the best approach.