# Difference between subprocess.Popen and os.system

Tags: python, subprocess, system

What is the difference between `subprocess.Popen()` and `os.system()`?

Answer (score 162, accepted):

If you check out the [subprocess section of the Python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-system), you'll notice there is an example of how to replace `os.system()` with `subprocess.Popen()`:

```
sts = os.system("mycmd" + " myarg")
```

...does the same thing as...

```
sts = Popen("mycmd" + " myarg", shell=True).wait()
```

The "improved" code looks more complicated, but it's better because once you know `subprocess.Popen()`, you don't need anything else. `subprocess.Popen()` replaces several other tools (`os.system()` is just one of those) that were scattered throughout three other Python modules.

If it helps, think of `subprocess.Popen()` as a very flexible `os.system()`.

Comment: You can also use `sts = p.wait()` instead of the last line.

Comment: @JacobMarble so suppose I am calling a selenium scraping script from another python script, which of these would allow me to complete the scraping script and then and only then execute the next line of code? As in, my scraping should complete before the execution can continue.

Comment: Maybe also mention http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess to point out that you ought to avoid the `shell=True` if you can.  Having this option is one of the benefits of `subprocess.Popen()` and its helper functions.

Comment: @PrakharMohanSrivastava If you want to block the flow and wait for command to complete its work check out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2837319/5252192

Comment: @PrakharMohanSrivastava, in general both `os.system` and `subprocess.call/popen/run` does block/wait for the command to finish: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14059648/4752883

Comment: (small fact) In 2022 if you take the same [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-system), `sts = os.system("mycmd" + " myarg")` becomes now `retcode = call("mycmd" + " myarg", shell=True)`

Answer (score 86):

`subprocess.Popen()` is strict super-set of `os.system()`.

Comment: This is the complete elegant answer.

Comment: It's elegant, but it's not complete, because it doesn't describe what `os.system` is missing, or why you might need `Popen`.

Comment: Not really enough to understand the solution. could have more elaborated with examples.

Answer (score 39):

`os.system` is equivalent to Unix [`system`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system) command, while `subprocess` was a helper module created to provide many of the facilities provided by the `Popen` commands with an easier and controllable interface. Those were designed similar to the [Unix Popen](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen) command.

> `system()` executes a command specified in command by calling `/bin/sh -c command`, and returns after the command has been completed

Whereas:

> The `popen()` function opens a process by creating a pipe, forking, and
> invoking the shell.

If you are thinking which one to use, then use **`subprocess`** definitely because you have all the facilities for execution, plus additional control over the process.

Comment: okay..then is there any way i can execute both os.system and popen in windows env ? i am a newbie and need to dig deeper..

Comment: Yes, you can use both os.system and subprocess in Windows Environment. Have a look at basic tutorials from effbot.org (Python Standard Library online book)

Answer (score 26):

Subprocess is based on popen2, and as such has a number of advantages - there's a full list in the [PEP here](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0324/), but some are:

- using pipe in the shell
- better newline support
- better handling of exceptions

Answer (score 10):

When running python (cpython) on windows the `<built-in function system>` [os.system](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) will execute under the curtains [_wsystem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/277bwbdz.aspx) while if you're using a non-windows os, it'll use [system](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html).

On contrary, Popen should use [CreateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) on windows and [_posixsubprocess.fork_exec](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/subprocess.py#L1423) in posix-based operating-systems.

That said, an important piece of advice comes from [os.system](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) docs, which says:

> The subprocess module provides more powerful facilities for spawning
>   new processes and retrieving their results; using that module is
>   preferable to using this function. See the Replacing Older Functions
>   with the subprocess Module section in the subprocess documentation for
>   some helpful recipes.