# Python: Failing to open a file using os.system()

Tags: python, system, cmd

I'm coding a Python script which is using the application [pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) a few times to perform some operations.

For example, I can use pdftk in the windows command line shell to merge two pdf files like this:

```
pdftk 1.pdf 2.pdf cat output result.pdf
```

I would like to perform the above operation in the middle of my Python script. Here's how I tried doing it:

```
os.system('pdftk 1.pdf 2.pdf cat output result.pdf')
```

The above pdftk command works perfectly in the Windows shell. However, it fails to open the input files (1.pdf and 2.pdf) when I'm trying to execute it using Python's `os.system()`. Here's the error message I get from pdftk when trying to execute the command using Python's `os.system()`:

> Error: Failed to open PDF file: 
>      1.pdf
>
> Error: Failed to open PDF file: 
>      2.pdf

Why does it happen? How can I fix it?

Please note: I know there are better ways to merge pdf files with Python. My question isn't about merging pdf files. That was just a toy example. What I'm trying to achieve is an ability to execute pdftk and other command line applications using Python.

Comment: It's almost certainly an issue with the directory paths. You could pass in the full path from `C:\` or wherever it is, or make sure you're starting in the right directory.

Comment: It can also be a quoting or shell variable interpolation issue. Always use the `subprocess` module instead of `os.system` to avoid such issues.

Comment: @chmullig: Do you really thing I'm that stupid? Well, turns out I am. The problem was indeed a path issue. Please repeat what you said in an answer to the question and I'll accept it. Thanks.

Comment: @Philipp: Could you please expand your remark on using subprocess instead of os.system? Why? What's the difference? Thanks.

Comment: by default, subprocess does not invoke a shell [so no variable expansion, etc].  Thus shell injection attacks fail.

Comment: @sna: `os.system` uses the shell, which requires arguments to be quotes in non-portable ways. The classes and functions in the `subprocess` module usually launch the process directly. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813238.

Comment: What's with this recent trend of answering questions with comments?  If you have an answer, POST AN ANSWER!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid (potential) problems with quoting, escaping, and so on, with `subprocess`:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(['pdftk', '1.pdf', '2.pdf', 'cat', 'output', 'result.pdf'])
```

It's just as easy to use as `os.system`, and even easier if you are building the argument list dynamically.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the current working directory of the process. If the .pdf files are located at `/some/path/to/pdf/files/`:

```
>>> os.getcwd()
'/home/vz0'
>>> os.chdir('/some/path/to/pdf/files/')
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are in the same current working directory.

Also I found using `\\` instead of `/` helped me.