# How does subprocess.call differ from os.system

Tags: python, subprocess, os.system

I have a python script to install/uninstall some regularly used programs for me and it also does some shortcut/folder clean up after uninstall. I used to use this code to delete a folder

```
os.system('rd /S /Q "{0}\\{1}"'.format(dirname, name))
```

which worked just fine. I am attempting to convert my usage of `os.system` to `subprocess.call` so I changed the above line to this

```
subprocess.call(['rd', '/S', '/Q', '{0}\\{1}'.format(dirname, name)])
```

but this gives the error

```
The system cannot find the file specified (2)
```

I must be using subprocess.call incorrectly but I can't work it out. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling an external command in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between subprocess.Popen and os.system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813238/difference-between-subprocess-popen-and-os-system)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that [`os.system`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.system) excutes in a subshell by default, whereas [`subprocess.call`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess.call#replacing-os-system) does not. Try using `shell=True`.

Comment: The problem is that there is no rd.exe, rd is implemented by cmd.exe and so must be used in a subshell to work. I replace my call with `os.rmdir(os.path.join(dirname, name))`