# Keep open a cmd window

Tags: python, windows, cmd

I have a python code in a program that opens a cmd window and runs there another program. The code looks like:

```
os.chdir('C:/Abaqus_JOBS' + JobDir)
os.system('abaqus job=' + JobName + '-3_run_rel2 user=FalseworkNmm41s interactive')
```

Now everything works but I get an error in the cmd window and next it closes very quickly not letting me see what was the error.
How can I prevent this cmd window to close?

Comment: Normally, `os.system` won't actually open a new cmd window for the other process. If you get one from `abaqus`, that's because of something Abaqus does itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `+ " & timeout 15"` or `+ " & pause"` to the string you pass to `os.system`:

```
os.chdir('C:/Abaqus_JOBS' + JobDir)
os.system('abaqus job=' + JobName + '-3_run_rel2 user=FalseworkNmm41s interactive' + " & timeout 15")
```

consider using `popen` ([Difference between subprocess.Popen and os.system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813238/difference-between-subprocess-popen-and-os-system)) instead.

Answer (score 2):

just use the commande "pause" it will ask you to press a key to continue.

Answer (score 1):

```
os.chdir('C:/Abaqus_JOBS' + JobDir)
os.system('abaqus job=' + JobName + '-3_run_rel2 user=FalseworkNmm41s interactive')
raw_input("Press Enter...")
```

Answer (score 1):

All of these work. I prefer the input("press enter"), but at fist I imported time, and added time.sleep(500), which would give me 500 secs to see what's going on. You can put in even more seconds.