# Use Python variable in bash command with os.system

Tags: python, macos, bash, variables, os.system

I would like to enter an phone number with `raw_input` and use this variable in my bash command for sending a message. I don't know how to set the variable $Phonenumber. Without the RAW Input, it works like a charm. I use Python 2.7.

```
import os

Phonenumber = raw_input("Number?)

os.system("yowsup-cli demos --login PHONE:PASSWORD= --send '$Phonenumber' 'MESSAGE'")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to stick with using `os.system` to make your calls, you can just format the command you pass to it:

```
import os
phone_number = raw_input("Number?")
os.system("yowsup-cli demos --login PHONE:PASSWORD= --send '{0}' 'MESSAGE'".format(phone_number))
```

However, chepner brings up a good point in his answer.  You should really be using the `subprocess` module for things like this, as it is a much more [flexible tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813238/difference-between-subprocess-popen-and-os-system).  To get the same behavior using `subprocess`, just pass a list to `subprocess.call` with the elements being all the space separated segments of your call:

```
import subprocess
phone_number = raw_input("Number?")
subprocess.call(["yowsup-cli", "demos", "--login" "PHONE:PASSWORD=", "--send", phone_number, "MESSAGE"])
```

You can check out more on `subprocess` [here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html).

Answer (score 5):

Use `subprocess` instead; among other features, it makes quoting much easier.

```
import subprocess

phone_number = raw_input("Number?")

subprocess.call(["yowsup-cli", "demos", "--login", "PHONE:PASSWORD=",
                 "--send", phone_number, "MESSAGE"])
```

Comment: subprocess is the better approach - and replaces popen (which is deprecated) ++

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
os.system("yowsup-cli demos --login PHONE:PASSWORD= --send '%d' 'MESSAGE'" % Phonenumber)
```

Comment: The method of Jake works. But with your solution I get an error (Thanks anyway):
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str

Comment: Replace the `%d` with `%s`