# How to change the convert command to python code

Tags: python, python-2.7, imagemagick-convert, wand

I'm using Imagemagick for image enhancement in my project. As I'm a newbie to Imagemagick, I have started it with using command line argument for this package. For further processing, I need to change the below command into python code.

```
convert sample.jpg -blur 2x1 -sharpen 0x3 -sharpen 0x3 -quality 100 -morphology erode diamond -auto-orient -enhance -contrast -contrast-stretch 0 -gamma .45455 -unsharp 0.25x0.25+8+0.065 -fuzz 2% output.jpg
```

I think it is possible using wand package. But is it possible to convert all the arguments using in the above command. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Try here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813238/difference-between-subprocess-popen-and-os-system.  os.system is generally considered less of a good idea as compared to popen

Comment: Actually, I couldn't proceed with those options(os.system and popen) as I have to upload the image to be converted dynamically. Is there any other options available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`os.system()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) to run terminal commands from Python.

```
import os

command = 'convert sample.jpg -blur 2x1 -sharpen 0x3 -sharpen 0x3 -quality 100 -morphology erode diamond -auto-orient -enhance -contrast -contrast-stretch 0 -gamma .45455 -unsharp 0.25x0.25+8+0.065 -fuzz 2% output.jpg'

os.system(command)
```

If you want to use the paths dynamically, you can also use the [`.format()`](https://pyformat.info/) method:

```
infile = 'sample.jpg'
outfile = 'output.jpg'

command = 'convert {} -blur 2x1 -sharpen 0x3 -sharpen 0x3 -quality 100 -morphology erode diamond -auto-orient -enhance -contrast -contrast-stretch 0 -gamma .45455 -unsharp 0.25x0.25+8+0.065 -fuzz 2% {}'.format(infile, outfile)

os.system(command)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Here how can we specify the file path? In my case, the file to convert is uploading dynamically.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Another option is **Wand, an ImageMagick binding for python** to convert the command mentioned above. Please refer the below link for more details:

[wand docs](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.3/)