# How to generate a specific number of files in a directory in python on linux

Tags: python, file

For example, I created a directory and want to populate it with a specified number of files.
For example

```
File 1 
File 2
File 3
etc . . .
File n
```

all in the same directory.

Comment: show your current code

Comment: don't have any code and not looking for any. Just want a hint for a starting point, like commands I should use or packages I should import

Comment: a hint: use `os` module. that's all

Comment: I understand that this method would call for a for loop also for the specified number of files to be created. Do you know the command to create files in python. (Still learning the langauge)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without `pathlib`, and cross-platform:

```
import os

target_path = "/path/to/target/dir"
files_num = 9

for i in range(files_num):
    with open(os.path.join(target_path, "File{}".format(i+1)), "a"):
        pass
```

Comment: `"/path/to/target/dir"` is not a very cross-platform path.

Comment: @planetp - actually, it is (as long as we're not talking about some obscure OSes or fringe Python implementations, of course). Python does automatic path conversions for all file operations, it's just that different OSes will mount different devices/partitions in different ways so Windows would expect to set a drive letter in the beginning if you want to select a different partition/device, but the above path will work perfectly fine for selecting the root path from your CWD be it Windows, Linux, BSD, OSX or any other flair of those.

Comment: Then why bother with `os.path.join()`?

Comment: Because while one cannot be responsible for user input (and both `target_path` and `files_num` are obviously user inputs here) that doesn't mean that the meat of a process should not follow best practices.

Answer (score 2):

If you're running Python 3.4+ you can do it easily with [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html):

```
from pathlib import Path

n = 9 
for i in range(1, n+1):
    Path(f"File{i}").touch()
```

Comment: Good call on `Path`! And funny how this was only introduced in Python 3.4. So useful!

Comment: I appreciate the help

Comment: This is Python 3.6+ only, format prefix is not available in earlier versions.

Comment: @zwer If you have an earlier version, then format with `str.format()` or `%`

Comment: Good call, yeah. I agree with making use of the string format method here.

Answer (score 1):

Python2/3 compliant, using `os.system`.

#### Unix/GNU

```
import os

for i in range(5):
    os.system('touch File%d' %i)
```

An alternative approach using `subprocess`, as suggested by idjaw:

```
import subprocess
for i in range(5):
    subprocess.Popen(['touch', 'File{}'.format(i)])
```

#### Windows

```
for i in range(5):
    os.system('type nul > File%d' %i)
```

#### OS Independent

```
for i in range(5):
    with open('File%d' %i, 'w') as f: pass
```

Comment: If you are going to go that route, you are better off using subprocess instead: `subprocess.Popen(['touch', 'file{}'.format(i)])`

Comment: @idjaw It's a clean alternative. But why would you prefer one over the other, in this instance?

Comment: To your point, absolutely a clean alternative. The `subprocess` module was introduced after `os.system`, therefore is more well supported and I believe supports more if you look to go more *advanced*. I'll point to some answers that discussed this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813238/difference-between-subprocess-popen-and-os-system). However, to not take away from your answer, for this example in particular, yes it provides a clean solution.

Comment: I never thought I'd see a platform-dependent way of creating a file in _python_, yet here we are. Just... just why?

Comment: @Rawing for the purpose of completeness, I suppose? I don't know, it is very late here.