# how to fix sh: 1 curl not found

Tags: python, linux-kernel, couchdb

I took a function for python that I have found online

```
def sh_escape(s):
return s.replace("(","\\(").replace(")","\\)").replace(" ","\\ ")
```

And I used it with os.system (). It looks like this:

```
os.system(sh_escape('curl -X PUT http://admin:admin@127.0.0.1:5984/test/')+file+sh_escape(' -d @/home/user/Downloads/') +file)
```

*file* is the name he reads with *os.walk()*

When I run it, I am becoming

```
sh: 1: curl -X PUT http://admin:admin@127.0.0.1:5984/test/file -d @/home/user/Downloads/file: not found
```

Do you know, where my mistake is ? if I run the command directly in the terminal it works.

Python 3 used

Comment: It is expecting a she-bang. Try subprocess without the shell: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813238/difference-between-subprocess-popen-and-os-system

Comment: Your `sh_escape` function escapes all the spaces, including the ones between the command and its arguments, and between all of the arguments. So you're not asking it to look for a command named `curl` on your PATH and run it with arguments `-X`, `PUT`, etc., but to find a command named `curl -X PUT …` on your PATH. And of course there is no such command.

Comment: More generally, why are you trying to reinvent multiple wheels here? Just use the `subprocess` module, and pass in a list of arguments.

Comment: thanks guys, the solution was with subprocess

Answer (score 2):

Did you install curl?
Mac os:
`brew install curl`
Linux:
`yum install curl or apt-get install curl`