# Replace os.system with os.popen for security purposes

Tags: python, popen, python-os

Is it possible to use `os.popen()` to achieve a result similar to `os.system`? I know that `os.popen()` is more secure, but I want to know how to be able to actually run the commands through this function. When using `os.system()`, things can get very insecure and I want to be able to have a secure way of accessing terminal commands.

Comment: Why do you think that `popen` is more secure?  It still invokes the shell…

Comment: `os.popen()` is exactly as insecure as `os.system()` is. If you want something more secure, use the `subprocess` module with the default `shell=False`. Where did you find a reference telling you that `os.popen()` was more secure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything that uses the shell to execute commands is insecure for obvious reasons (you don't want someone running `rm -rf /` in your shell :). Both `os.system` and `os.popen` use the shell.

For security, use the `subprocess` module with `shell = False`

Either way, both of those functions have been deprecated since Python 2.6

Comment: Sidenote: What is the difference, then, between `os.system()` and `os.popen()`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813238/difference-between-subprocess-popen-and-os-system