# How can I download a file that is offered to me to download through an http request?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm trying to download a stored file on file.io, but the problem is that I get a 2kb file. How can I download it?
When opening the link in the browser I get the download window. Here there is the code I'm using.

```
url = "https://www.file.io/"
r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
filename = "filedownloaded"
open(filename, 'wb').write(r.content)
```

Comment: Is the download initiated via javascript?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

file.io has an api for cURL that is very easy to use.

You need to know the target file extension and one time url. For example if I upload a png to file.io this would be my cURL request and the file will be downloaded in the current directory.

`curl -o test.png https://file.io/fileURL`

Since you are writing a script for this I am assuming that you will have this information.

```
import os
directory = "cd /target/directory/"
curlReq = "curl -o "
#you will have to retrive the info for these variables
filename = "filename.extension "
url = "https://file.io/uniqueURL"

os.system(directory)
os.system(curlReq + filename + url)
```

I there might be other ways but this worked for me.

*EDIT:* cURL request using subprocess.

```
from subprocess import call

url = "https://file.io/uniqueURL"
filename = "filename.extension"
call(["cd","/target/directory/"])
call(["curl","-o",filename,url])
```

Comment: An API _for cURL_ ? Also, why use `os.system()` instead of the subprocess module, the latter of which is recommend by the docs for the former?

Comment: @AMC I edited my post to include the subprocess module. What is the benefit of this over os?

Comment: You can find some information on the subject [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813238/difference-between-subprocess-popen-and-os-system) and [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system). :)