# Command in Python

Tags: python, mysql

I write script in Python and I have some problems, I need to run a command with a parameter that I get from the database, I did so (addition mysql.connector installed):

```
import mysql.connector
import os
 
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="name",
  password="pass",
  database="base"
)
 
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
 
mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `employee` LIMIT 2")
 
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
 
for row in myresult:
    os.system('command ' + row[1])
```

I have 3 questions:

1. is it correct that I use os and not subprocess?
2. I get an answer in json format when I run this command, how do I get the value from there? Do I need to include "import json"?

```
import json
 
# some JSON:
x = '{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}'
 
# parse x:
y = json.loads(x)
 
# the result is a Python dictionary:
print(y["age"])
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish here? `command` prevents function and alias lookup, but a noninteractive shell won't have any functions or aliases defined in the first place. If it's a standin for some _other_ command, and you want to be safe against command injections, it very much won't help.

Comment: Consider the case where your database contains `$(rm -rf ~)` -- `yourcommand $(rm -rf ~)` is going to delete everything in your home directory before `yourcommand` ever gets started.

Comment: Also, note that each Stack Overflow question should be about _only one_ underlying question. @FLAK-ZOSO is slightly going against the rules to help you by answering a multi-question "question" (see [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), particularly the section _Answer Well-Asked Questions_, and the bullet point therein regarding questions that "require too much guidance for you to answer in full, **or request answers to multiple questions**").

Comment: ...following that rule helps us provide the best possible answer for each subquestion (often, the best way to do that is to redirect via the close-as-duplicate mechanism to a preexisting, already-answered instance of a question that the community has put a lot of time and effort into answering comprehensively).

Answer (score 0):

> is it correct that I use os and not subprocess?

You really should use `subprocess`, if you are asking *why* you should read [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813238/difference-between-subprocess-popen-and-os-system).

---

> Do I need to include "import json"?

In Python `import <module>` has a very similar usage to `C`/`C++` `#include <module>` preprocessor directive, even if it has some differences. So you don't *include import json*, but you *import json*.

Anyway `json` is a Python built-in module which parses, encodes, indents and writes to `.json` files, and if you get a `JSON` format response you really should consider it to decode this `object` to a Python `dict`.

Comment: I _wholeheartedly_ disagree with this advice. There is **never** a reason to use `os.system()` instead of `subprocess`, and a great many good reasons to avoid it. `os.system()` is incapable of running without an implied `/bin/sh -c`; it doesn't provide the ability to override the PATH or other environment variables; it doesn't provide the ability to choose the shell code will be run with; it doesn't provide the ability to directly control the argv -- why would you start with something that's antiquated?

Comment: You are for sure right, I've read a lot of Q&A about os/subprocess, but the OP seems to don't know the difference between "include import json" and "import json", so I don't think it's very important for them.

Comment: Ok @CharlesDuffy, I'm editing my answer since "why would you start with something that's antiquated?" convinced me, thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think a _really good_ answer would require a clarification from the OP before it can be written. I don't know if they mean `command` to refer to the shell builtin named `command` or some arbitrary command of their own; and also don't know how many arguments they expect the database content to expand to -- but something like `subprocess.call(['theircommand', row[1]])` is generally going to have considerably fewer security faults; or `subprocess.call(['theircommand'] + shlex.split(row[1]))` if they expect a string from which multiple arguments can be extracted.

Comment: I checked version python, subprocess for version over 3.5, right?

Comment: Yes, are you using an older version? You shouldn't, versions over 3.5 have some useful features, in particular I remember that a lot of changes were introduced with 3.6 and 3.9 (and now with 3.10, which is probably the minor release with the major amount of new features).