# Python popen shell command wait till subprocess has finished

Tags: python, subprocess, popen, imagemagick-convert

I know this question has been answered before here [Python popen command. Wait until the command is finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837214/python-popen-command-wait-until-the-command-is-finished)
but the thing is I don't understand the answer and how I can apply it to my code so please dont flag this question as being asked before without a little help please:)

I have a function that takes in a shell command and executes it and returns variable outputs.

It works fine except I dont want the flow of control to continue untill the process has completely finished. The reason for this is that I am creating images using the imagemagick command line tool and when I try and access them for information shortly afterward they are incomplete. This is my code..

```
def send_to_imagemagick(self, shell_command):

    try:
        # log.info('Shell command = {0}'.format(shell_command))
        description=os.popen(shell_command)
        # log.info('description = {0}'.format(description))            
    except Exception as e:
        log.info('Error with Img cmd tool {0}'.format(e))

    while True:
        line = description.readline()
        if not line: break
        return line
```

Thank you so much @Ruben This is what I used to finish it off so it returns the outputs correctly.

```
 def send_to_imagemagick(self, shell_command):

        args = shell_command.split(' ')    
        try:                
            description=Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
            out, err = description.communicate()
            return out

        except Exception as e:
            log.info('Error with Img cmd tool {0}'.format(e))
```

Comment: Why use `os.popen` and not `subprocess.popen`? Subprocess replaces os.popen.
And I think you want to do this: `description.communicate()` to wait till it's finished.
See https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate

Comment: So how do I write it? like this ...description= subprocess.call([shell_command])

Comment: `return line` will break the `while` loop because the function will exit, I think you should use `yield line` here instead of `return`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `subprocess.popen`:

> This module intends to replace several older modules and functions.

So in your case `import subprocess`
and then use `popen.communicate()` to wait until your command finished.

For the documentation on this see: [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate)

So:

```
from subprocess import Popen

def send_to_imagemagick(self, shell_command):

    try:
        # log.info('Shell command = {0}'.format(shell_command))
        description=Popen(shell_command)
        description.communicate()

        # log.info('description = {0}'.format(description))            
    except Exception as e:
        log.info('Error with Img cmd tool {0}'.format(e))

    while True:
        line = description.readline()
        if not line: break
        return line
```

Comment: Sorry for capital error :)

Comment: `return line` or `yield line`? Also is that `self` argument correct?

Comment: I don't know, ask OP.

Comment: Hmm...okay, didn't see that you just copy-paste OP's code and changed the `os.popen` part of it :P

Comment: I didn't even look at that `while`. Looks weird tho, I agree on that.

Comment: Thanks Ruben. I have tried that but now I get a thiss error "No such file or directory" Does Popen need more arguments in the shell command?

Comment: Your command has to be in a `list` so if you want to `echo whoopididoo` your shell_command would be `['echo', 'whoopididoo']`.

Comment: Ok Thsnks a mill. I see

Comment: @Ruben So how would you put this shell command  in a list?...  "identify  -format "%b:%w:%h:%r:%#" myimage.jpg"

Comment: You can use `string.split(" ")` to do this so it becomes: `['identify','-format', '"%b:%w:%h:%r:%#"','myimage.jpg']`

Comment: @Ruben `split(' ')` doesn't do enough, you also have to loose the " around the next to last argument.

Comment: Thanks guys that seems to be working . the only thing is Im not returning it properly now. Any suggestions?