# how do I make my python program to wait for the subprocess to be completed

Tags: python-3.x, batch-file, subprocess, popen

I have a python program which should execute a command line (command line is a psexec command to call a batch file on the remote server)
I used **popen** to call the command line. The batch on the remote server produces a return code of **0**.
Now I have to wait for this return code and on the basis of the return code I should continue my program execution.
I tried to use .wait() or .check_output() but for some reason did not work for me.

```
cmd = """psexec -u CORPORATE\user1 -p force \\\sgeinteg27 -s cmd /c "C:\\Planview\\Interfaces\\ProjectPlace_Sree\\PP_Run.bat" """
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, bufsize=2048, shell=True,
stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p.wait()
print(p.returncode)
##The below block should wait until the above command runs completely.
##And depending on the return code being ZERO i should continue the rest of 
##the execution.

if p.returncode ==0:
    result = tr.test_readXid.readQuery(cert,planning_code)
    print("This is printed depending if the return code is zero")
```

[Here is the EOF the batch file execution and the return code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXamN.png)
Can anybody help me with this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python popen command. Wait until the command is finished](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837214/python-popen-command-wait-until-the-command-is-finished)

Comment: Thank you ! communicate() worked for me. With this I'm able to make my program wait until the Return code is zero.