# Python-Continue script only after bat file is finished

Tags: python-2.7

I have a series of code like below.In test.Bat file contains code,it will terminate after its code completion.
Everything is working fine,But When i try to run a python script-it prints finished when the batch file was running

```
from subprocess import Popen
print "start"
Popen("C:\Users\test.Bat")
print "Finished"
```

I want to print "Finished" after exceution completion of batch file..How can i achieve that

Comment: Have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837214/python-popen-command-wait-until-the-command-is-finished

Comment: @ZeusNet ,'p = subprocess.Popen(([data["om_points"], ">", diz['d']+"/points.xml"])' What does it mean.How can i achieve from that to this

Comment: `import subprocess as sub print "start"  sub.POpen("C:\\Users\test.bat") \n sub.communicate()  print "finished"` should be the solution for your example

Comment: thanks,now its working