# threading.join() does not wait for threads to finish

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

As mentioned I the title. I am using Python 2.7 in the Spyder IDE. My problem is that in my loop all the threads get started at once...this kills my pc. Thats why I only want 2 of them at a time. I understood that join  waits for the thread to finish? did I misunderstood that?

```
    def func1(string):
        subprocess.Popen(string , shell= True)

    for i in range(0,A):
        j = 0
        check = False
        tl=[]
        while j <= B : 
            string = 'python do.py'+ ' '+str(i)+' '+str( j)+' '+ str( 3)
            t = threading.Thread(target=func1,args=[string])       
            t.start()
            tl.append(t)
            string = 'python do.py'+ ' '+str(i)+' '+str( j)+' '+ str( 3)
            t = threading.Thread(target=func1,args=[string])       
            t.start()
            tl.append(t)
            for t in tl:
               t.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

join does wait for thread to complete, but `subprocess.Popen()` not. 
try using `subprocess.call()` instead.

see more here: [Python popen command. Wait until the command is finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837214/python-popen-command-wait-until-the-command-is-finished)