# Unable to read file because of unfinished subprocess: Python

Tags: python, r, subprocess

I'm using `subprocess` to run a `script.R` file from `test.py`. My `test.py` goes as:

```
import subprocess
import pandas as pd
subprocess.call(["/usr/bin/Rscript", "--vanilla", "script.R"])   #line 3
df=pd.read_csv("output.csv")                                     #line 4
```

`script.R` goes as:

```
library(limma)
df <- read.csv("input.csv")
df<-normalizeCyclicLoess(df)
write.csv(df,"output.csv")
```

When I run the above file (`test.py`), I get an error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'output.csv' does not exist: b'output.csv'
```

I understand that this error is because a `output.csv` file doesn't exist in my working directory. But, I assume that it would be created by `script.R`, which isn't happening probably because before the execution of `line 3` finishes, python goes to `line 4`. We used help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837214/python-popen-command-wait-until-the-command-is-finished) for this, and as mentioned, we are using `call` for this. What's going wrong then? Thanks...

**EDIT**: I noticed that if I don't import any libraries in my code (like `limma` above), everything works fine. I can write any lengthy code as I want, and it doesn't give me any error and proceeds to completion. But, as soon as I import any library, `subprocess.call(....)` gives me a non-zero result (zero means process completed). For a test, I changed my `script.R` to `library(limma)` (and nothing else) (tried for other libraries too- got the same results), and it gave me a non-zero result. Thus, I think, there's some problem with the import of libraries using `subprocess`. Please note that I'm able to run this R code directly, and nothing is wrong with my code/library. Please give me some hints on what might be going wrong here...

Comment: Your assumption seems to be incorrect. `subprocess.call()` is described in the docs: "Run the command described by args. Wait for command to complete.".

Comment: @VPfB if that's the case, then why am I getting this error? Can you please give some hints?

Comment: I'm sorry, I know Python, but not R. I would add some debugging print statements to see what is happening and when.

Comment: @VPfB My R code works fine if I run directly

Answer (score -1):

Apologies, my initial answer was completely wrong.

Your subprocess call:

```
subprocess.call(["/usr/bin/Rscript", "--vanilla", "script.R"])
```

will return a number - this is the exit code of the process. If it succeeds, without error, it should be zero. You could check this to make sure your R code ran correctly.

Have you tried running your R code directly? Does it produce the output.csv? And if so, does it produce it in the right place?

Comment: It gives me `'int' object has no attribute 'wait'`

Comment: My R code runs perfectly directly. And no, it doesn't return a zero. I always get  a non-zero (`-11`) output.