# rsync or any other way to copy files to a new directory using Python

Tags: python, glob, rsync

```
query = 'rsync -zavP server@10.10.0.160:/home/server/Catalog/ /home/user/sample'
os.popen(query)
os.chdir('/home/user/sample')
files = glob.glob(*.*)
```

Rsync works great. The files are copied, and a sample subdirectory is created in the user directory, which did not exist before. But when I try to get a list of files, it turns out to be empty. The fact is that until the script finishes working, the OS will not update information about the contents of the directories. If you split rsync and glob into two different scripts and run them sequentially manually, you will get a list of files. How  to copy files to a new non-existent directory and immediately get a list of files in one script? Thank you!

Comment: I think `os.popen` won't wait for completion. You probably have to [follow this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58960291/6699447) to wait the process to be completed.

Comment: Exactly. You can try in other ways, for example through os.walk. The result will be the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use `os.scandir()` from `os` module or go for `pathlib` module and use `iterdir()` to list everything. These are preferred methods over `os.listdir()` as they show the modified time as well.

I do believe instead of using two separate scripts, you can go for two separate functions; this way, you ensure that the listing happens after the first function - copy - has been finished.
For instance:

```
def copy_files():
  rsync ...
  return

def list_files():
  os.scandir()
  ...
```

Another thing would be using some wait methods:

```
from waiting import wait
...
wait(YOUR_FUNCTION(), ...)
...
```

I do not reckon that the `sleep()` function would be useful here; as you are not aware of the amount of time spent on copying.

Last but not least, you can also use rsync flags to show the progress/files copied.

Hope it helps.